# jQuery Drag-and-Drop + click Image Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

I would like to have a simple drop zone to upload image via AJAX and jQuery. I have found some plugins but they are way too customized for what's needed, and I cannot get any of them working properly.
**I also would like the drop zone to be clickable, in order to manually choose a file from the OS file dialog.**

I found this script, that works fine but where the drop zone is not clickable:

```
// ---------------------------- drop zone to upload image : '#dropfile'
$(document).on('dragenter', '#dropfile', function() {
            return false;
});
 
$(document).on('dragover', '#dropfile', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
});
 
$(document).on('dragleave', '#dropfile', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
});

$(document).on('drop', '#dropfile', function(e) {
            if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
                       if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
                                   // Stop the propagation of the event
                                   e.preventDefault();
                                   e.stopPropagation();
                                   // Main function to upload
                                   upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
                       }
            }
            return false;
});

function upload(files) {
            var f = files[0] ;
 
            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image/jpeg')) {
                       alert(‘The file must be a jpeg image’) ;
                       return false ;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // When the image is loaded, run handleReaderLoad function
            reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);            
}

function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
            var pic = {};
            pic.file = evt.target.result.split(',')[1];
            var str = jQuery.param(pic);
            $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: ‘url_to_php_script.php’,
                       data: str,
                       success: function(data) {
                                   //do_something(data) ;
                       }
            });
}
```

**So I added an invisible file type input, but image data seems to be sent twice**. I suppose it's due a bad event propagation with the original drop zone:

```
// ---------------------------- clickable drop zone with invisible file input '#inputFile'
$('#dropfile).on('click', function() {
    $('input#inputFile').trigger('click');
    $('input#inputFile').change(function(e) {
        upload($('input#inputFile')[0].files);
    });
});
```

I tried to add these lines but data is always sent twice:

```
$('#dropfile).on('click', function() {
    $('input#inputFile').trigger('click');
    $('input#inputFile').change(function(e) {
        upload($('input#inputFile')[0].files);
        // -------------- stop sending data twice ???
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why data is sent twice but I found a better script here:
https://makitweb.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-with-jquery-and-ajax/